# Empty string is not allowed error when adding or renaming item on Sitecore content tree

Tags: content-editor

Getting the error below in the CMS when trying to insert items into content tree or when re-naming existing items

[image]

```
Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Empty string is not allowed.
Parameter name: validation.
Actual value was .
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.AssertString(String argument, String name, Boolean allowEmpty)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.SheerResponse.Input(String text, String defaultValue, String validation, String validationText, Int32 maxLength)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.AddMaster.Add(ClientPipelineArgs args)
```

Any chance you can help figure out what is going on?

Comment: Do you have popups blocked?   looks like the dialog where you normally enter the name, gets blocked and therefore returns empty string.

Comment: Can you check if the value of this setting  is <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="." />    ?

Comment: can you change to this value : <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\w\*\$][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />

Comment: I have checked, the <setting name="ItemNameValidation" had somehow the value set to empty string. I have restored the regex and this has resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: I change my comment into an answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, I think this answer may be applicable to previous versions, I am using 10.2, there is a regex already provided but still the same error.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPXg0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPXg0.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem of your issue is **ItemNameValidation** settings. 
Please change the value of this setting to the default one :

```
 <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\w*\$][\w\s\-\$]*((\d{1,})){0,1}$" />
```